# Simple Configuration Nginx and Varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish, remote-server

I have 3 computers on same network(LAN). And I want to configure one computer as Nginx Web-Server, and another as Varnish Cache server and one client . I succesfully installed one(let's say A) Nginx ( 192.168.0.15 ) and B Varnish( 192.168.0.20 ). I configured  A  as a webserver and I can browse the index.html from other computers. But I couldn't connect it with B.
I messed up with "nginx.conf" and "/sites-available/server.com" and Varnish's "default.vcl"

Could you give me the basic configurations which suit my environment ?

If you want to take a look
My nginx.conf :

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream dynamic_node {
            server 1.1.1.1:80; # 1.1.1.1 is the IP of the Dynamic Node
        }
    server {
        listen      81;
        server_name  myserver.myhome.com;
        location / {
        #root /var/www/server.com/public_html;
        #index index.html index.htm;

        # pass the request on to Varnish
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.20;

        # Pass a bunch of headers to the downstream server.
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_redirect     off; 
        }
    }
}
```

/sites-available/server.com :

server {

```
listen   80;
server_name myserver.myhome.com;

access_log /var/www/server.com/access.log;
error_log /var/www/server.com/error.log;
```

}

And default.vcl like this :

```
backend web1 {
    .host = "192.168.0.15";
    .port = "8080";
}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "192.168.0.15") {

        #set req.http.host = "myserver.myhome.com";
        set req.backend = web1;
    }   
}
```

Lastly  /etc/default/varnish :

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can use nginx upstream for backend - which is varnish.  Ensure that ip addresses and ports match

Comment: proxy_pass should work too provided varnish is pointing to that ip address/port

Comment: Set all ports=81(except DAEMON_OPTS)  and I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway at localhost:81

Comment: specify the port number in proxy_pass for nginx - this needs to be the port on which varnish is listening for connections

Comment: I changed **proxy_pass** as http://192.168.0.20:8080;(and tried 6081) and I try to get varnish headers by **curl -I 192.168.0.15** but I couldn't get. I'm newbie to server configuration, so could you show me the proper way ?

Comment: as per my answer - the port number in proxy_pass should match the port number in the DAEMON_OPTS section (a flag) - currently set to 6081

Comment: does it work on the same computer but with different ports?  If so, then recheck when using separate computers -> reconfirm ip address on which varnish is listening on - whether its the one you are using or something else (use netstat to confirm if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right now, your varnish instance is listening on port 6081.  This needs to be specified in the proxy_pass for nginx e.g.

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.0.20:6081
```

I am assuming that the ip addresses you mentioned are correct and network connection between the computers is not restricted.

**Update**

Please bear in mind that you can use nginx in front of varnish or the other way around.  Both nginx and varnish can serve as proxies to back end services.
Your current implementation is using nginx as the proxy.  This means that you can rely on proxy_pass or use upstream module in nginx (in case you wish to load balance behind with multiple varnish instances with just one nginx in front).  Essentially, whichever is the proxy, the ip address and port number for the backend specified in the proxy (nginx in your case) must match the ip address and port number for the backend service (varnish in your case).  The backend in varnish would need to match the ip address and port number for whichever application server/service you are using (tomcat/netty/django/ror etc.).

Comment: But is *backend web1 {
    .host = "192.168.0.15";
    .port = "8080";
}* configuration true ?

Comment: I'm updating the answer to respond to your question

Comment: Now I understand very well. Last question : for backend server (tomcat/netty you said) if I configure varnish as **backend web1 { .host = "192.168.0.25"; .port = "8080"; }** let's say 192.168.0.25 actual web server, what'll be the configuration for that webserver ? Should I specify the listen port to 8080 ?

Comment: if you specify backend web1 { .host = "192.168.0.25"; .port = "8080"; } in varnish, your backend web server should be running on that ip address and port i.e. 192.168.0.25 & 8080.  Hope it helps